# Reload Python Class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know I can reload a module with:

```
from someplace import module
reload(module)
```

But now I'm looking for a way to only reload a class instead of a module. Basically something that would update class after this statement:

```
from someplace.module import class
```

Comment: Why do you want to only reload one class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible, since the modules are compiled by the Python interpreter as a whole, exposing the symbols at the end of this process.

If you really need this, perhaps try putting that class into a separate module.

Note: if you only need this to ease your development, try [ipython %autoreload](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html). It will reload the modules for you automatically when you make a change.